# Trying to determine a specific database normalization issue

Tags: database-design, normalization

A coworker sketched out the values of a new table as:

```
"Foo", "some value 1"
"Foo", "some value 2"
"Foo", "some value 3"
"Bar", "some value 3"
```

These are the only columns in the table.  The column names are Col1, Col2.

One person said that this table is not normalized, another said it is.

The specific argument that it violated normalization is that removing the three records with "Foo" in Col1 "Foo" would no longer be present in the system.  That person said there should be a lookup table containing an ID, and Name column.  The table above would reference the Id of that table as its FK.

The argument that it wasn't normalized is that there wasn't a third column in the table dependent on the first (3rd normalized form).

The confusion I think comes from it being 1NF in that it satisfies this example:

```
Customer    Tr. ID  Date            Amount
Jones   12890   14-Oct-2003     -87
Jones   12904   15-Oct-2003     -50
Wilkins     12898   14-Oct-2003     -21
Stevens     12907   15-Oct-2003     -18
Stevens     14920   20-Nov-2003     -70
Stevens     15003   27-Nov-2003     -60
```

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

But it sounds like it violates this rule, "The same information can be expressed on multiple rows; therefore updates to the table may result in logical inconsistencies."  This applies to normalization beyond 1NF.

So it looks like the original table would violate 2NF, and thereby 3NF, but would satisfy 1NF. Is this correct?

Comment: Err, thanks Rich B, but I'm still confused.

Comment: OK so I did not ask "What is Normalization".  I asked if this particular instance violated a rule of normalization.  Why not actually answer the question instead of changing the title and then responding to that.  You are not answering the actual question.

Comment: My confusion is with how you "worded" your sample data.  What are the field names?  What does the record look like?  Is "foo" data?  Then no, it's not normalized, since you're repeating data.

Comment: @blu we need more information about the actual data being represented and its relationship to the surrounding data to be able to answer.

Comment: @Adrien: Repeating data doesn't make a table non-normalized in any sane usage. Two people, for example, can have the same first name and almost no one would split off a first names table because of that. Or, even if they did split off the first names table, that column could be a foreign key.

Comment: Based on the question, it is debatable whether you no what normalization is.

Comment: @derobert: Agreed.  I worded my comment poorly.  I was interpreting it as "foo" and "bar" were intended to be key values.  I don't seem to be communicating well this afternoon.  I blame it on being too sober.

Comment: @TheTXI when the three records for "Foo" are removed "Foo" no longer exists in the system.  That sounded like a normalization issue.  One person said it would need a third column dependent on one of the other two to violate 3rd normalized form.

Comment: @derobert repeating data only makes the table non-normalized if the entire row repeats.  Also, repeating something like a first name, will in no way de-normalize a table, unless something is somehow functionally dependent on the first name and derivable by just that.

Comment: I realize I did not formulate the original question very well, thank you to those who assisted in constructing a more accurate question.  For those that were not constructive, isn't there something better you can do?

Comment: As to the new question you added, if "Some value 1" can be derived from "Foo", or "Bar" can be derived from "Some value 3". If there is a PK spanning Col1 & Col2, then it is still in 2NF and 3NF.  You'd have to add a column that is not a part of the key to violate either, and then it would have to be derivable from only Col1 or only Col2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those two columns are really all there are, then I would say this database table is in third normal form. Here's my reasoning:

1. It's **CLEARLY** in 1NF since none of the attributes are "multi-valued"
2. Since neither col1 nor col2 are a valid key candidate (duplicate values!), the only possible and valid primary key on this table is (col1,col2)
3. 2NF stipulates that no non-prime attribute shall be functionally dependent on a part of a candidate key. Since there are only col1 and col2 which are both part of the only possible candidate key, this point is moot - the table **IS** in 2NF
4. 3NF according to E.F.Codd basically says that any non-key attribute must be dependent "on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key". Since we **ONLY** have two columns which make up the key, there are no other non-key attributes, so none of the non-key attributes violates this rule --> the table **IS** is 3NF

I don't know if your work buddy wants to really get into 4NF, 5NF or Boyce-Codd NF - I highly doubt it......

Marc

Comment: Exactly, thank you. "Every element must be dependant on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd!"

Answer (score 2):

There are different normalization levels. But without the actual field names, you can't really know if you need to normalize.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

There are a few [different levels of normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If "Foo", "some value 1" "Foo", "some value 2" "Foo", "some value 3" "Bar", "some value 3"
means that the table would look like:

```
Col1| Col2
------------------
Foo | some value 1
Foo | some value 2
Foo | some value 3
Bar | some value 3
```

And there is a primary key on Col1/Col2 then yes, it is 'Normalized'.
 
If there is no key at all, then no, it is not normalized, as you could insert another instance of "Bar", "some value 3".

As to the new question you added:
 If there is a PK spanning Col1 & Col2, then it is still in 2NF and 3NF.  You'd have to add a column that is not a part of the key to violate either, and then it would have to be derivable from only Col1 or only Col2.

Comment: No those were the only columns.  The person wanted to use Col1 to do joins into another table.

Comment: @blu if there is a primary key or uniqueness spanning Col1 & Col2 then it is normalized.  If there is not then it violates 1st Normal Form.

Comment: Thank you for a constructive answer

Comment: np, normalization isn't something I'd expect someone to grasp in 5 seconds. I updated the answer to cover the additions to your question that you added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the list of values in the table represent four rows:

```
col1 col2
Foo  some value 1
Foo  some value 2
Foo  some value 3 
Bar  some value 3
```

Based on my understanding, this table would be considered normalized. I would expect the primary key here to be a composite key of {col1, col2}.

I would normally expect to see this type of many-to-many mapping of values in a table when col1 and col2 are each foreign keys into other tables that contain additional attributes of the entities being mapped.

I would also recommend considering numeric keys rather than these nvarchar values. I suspect that these textual values may not be good candidate keys for the entities they represent, but I don't have enough information to fully make that judgment.

Comment: I know the table outlined is awful, I would never do something like this.  When asked, "why", I said it violates normalization to which I was told no, its normalized.

Comment: With the primary key being {col1, col2}, I would consider this normalized. Do you have enough information to justify why changes would be recommended, though?